# Союз "не только, но также"

Tags: союзы

Вопрос следующий: в конструкциях типа "... отличается не только тем-то, но также тем-то..." нужен союз "и" (не только, но также и)? И является ли его наличие обязательным?

Answer (score 1):

> …нужен союз "и" (не только, но также и)? **И является ли его наличие**
>   **обязательным?**

**Не является.**  *"Не только... но также"* встречается без *"и"* даже в "Русской грамматике".

См. http://rusgram.narod.ru/1706-1719.html :

> **§ 1708.**
>   *...Эти единицы принадлежат **не только** синтаксису, **но  также** лексике и морфологии…*

Comment: Во! Это убедительный пример! Я, когда свою "философию" писал, что-то такое и имел в виду.

Comment: В этом примере обращает на себя внимание союз "и", завершающий перечисление двух элементов после "также". Наличие второго подряд "и" (в составе "также и") здесь воспринималось бы хуже, чем в случае без перечисления (с собственным "и") - видимо, и в составе  "также и" "и" выполняет подобную "завершающую" функцию. Поэтому наличие или отсутствие во второй части предложения перечисления со своим "и" может служить ориентиром для выбора между "но также" и "но также и".

Comment: "Во фразеологическом словаре русского языка даны **не только** сами фразеологизмы с их толкованиями, **но также** примеры их стилистического употребления". https://books.google.ru/books?id=knGkBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA3&dq=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%22+%22%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5%22+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=i690VfXpB6H9ywPAyIPYDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%22%20%22%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Надо контекст смотреть.
Мне кажется, что "И" здесь нельзя отнести к обязательно части, хотя в грамматике союз "не только, но также" не упоминается. 
Есть союз "не только, но и".
Но в этом составном союзе "И" выполнят роль усилительной частицы, поэтому убедительного довода за то, что без него нельзя, я не вижу. Хотя, если честно, язык сам просит его поставить.

"Так же", понятно, не обязательно, но вполне возможно.

Answer (score 0):

Интересно то, что градационный союз НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО ТАКЖЕ используется в литературе достаточно часто и он синонимичен союзу НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО И.

Можно предположить, что его применение связано со стилевыми особенностями текста, например:

(1) Это касается НЕ ТОЛЬКО науки, НО ТАКЖЕ искусства и политики, в которой также должен быть свой профессионализм (Дмитрий Лихачев). Здесь неудобно сочетание двух "и" в сочетании "но и искусства".

(2) Как видите, он уже НЕ ТОЛЬКО был искушен в ассонансах, внутренних рифмах, звуковых повторах, НО И позволял себе разбивать четырехстопный ямб инородной строчкой, что показывало его знакомство НЕ ТОЛЬКО с обязательным Пушкиным, но ТАКЖЕс Тютчевым и даже Андреем Белым (В. П. Катаев).  Здесь встречаются два союза в одном предложении.

Comment: Спасибо всем большое. Меня  именно смутило, что упоминания о союзе "не только... но также" нету. Тем не менее, есть множество примеров его употребления. Хотя действительно есть союз "не только... но и", а "также" всего лишь усилительная частица. Как она может влиять на основной состав союза? Или может? Но, главное, есть много таких примеров, где допустимо написание без "и".