# Не только... а также: правильно ли?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Те из лингвистов, кто занимается исследованием языка художественной литературы, не сомневаются в особой роли глагола не только в поэтическом, а также в прозаическом тексте.

Грамотно ли составлено это предложение? Если нет, то в чем ошибка?

Comment: я не носитель языка но рискну и согласую число: "Те из лингвистов, которые занимаются ... , не сомневаются ...".

Comment: Нет, тут всё нормально: с КТО в придаточном употребляется единственное число, с ТЕ в главном  - множественное число глагола-сказуемого.

Comment: Смешно! Aer, вы отметили как лучший ответ, в котором полностью обойдены заданные Вами вопросы: "Грамотно ли составлено это предложение? Если нет, то в чем ошибка?" Ну и как, теперь знаете ответ?

Comment: @slava1947 не вижу шуток. Во-первых, принятый ответ не равно лучший ответ; как лучший я ничего не отмечал. Тот ответ, который с галочкой, содержит важные указания и ссылки, которые мне помогли. Во-вторых, ответ теперь знаю: в ЕГЭ в восьмом задании (на, внимание, грамматику, а не на что бы там еще ни было) есть совершенно не понятно как связанное с грамматикой требование употреблять двойной союз «не только... но и...», и никакой больше (спасибо Екатерине Каштановой!).

Comment: Aer: _"Во-первых, принятый ответ не равно лучший ответ; как лучший я ничего не отвечал"_. ===  Да бросьте...  Навожу курсор на галочку, читаю: _"Автор вопроса отметил ответ **как лучший** 6 часов назад"_.

Comment: @slava1947 это неточность перевода, разберемся, спасибо. https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer — вот Справка.

Comment: Вопрос о союзе "не только...но также" уже обсуждался: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416243/Союз-не-только-но-также  И ссылка на "Русскую грамматику там есть".

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова: спасибо за объяснение! три года учу русский язык, но мало понимаю до сих пор =) jajajajaja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Многие считают, что единственно правильным союзом является союз ***не только...но и.*** Однако в новых словарях указывается, что нормированными являются и другие союзы:***не только… а*** и ***не только… а и***

Из словаря Ефремовой:

https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%E2%80%A6_%D0%B0_%D0%B8

***не только… а*** и ***не только… а и*** союз

Употребляется при соединении однородных членов предложения (второй из которых противопоставляется первому как более существенному), соответствуя по значению сл.: не только… но и.

Современный толковый словарь русского языка

2) Также: **Русская грамматика **http://rusgram.narod.ru/index1.html

http://rusgram.narod.ru/1669-1688.html

§ 1681. Синтагматически автономные двухместные союзные соединения строятся по схемам: 1) "союз – коррелят", **2) "союз – союз",** 3) "вводное слово (или словосочетание) – союз".

2) Соединения, построенные **по схеме "союз – союз";** различаются по функциональному и формальному признакам объединяемых компонентов. а) Соединены два семантически и формально близких компонента: поскольку – постольку; постольку – поскольку; сколько – столько; столько – сколько; столько же – сколько и (книжн.); не столько – сколько; столь же – сколь (книжн.); столько же – как и; насколько – настолько; чем – тем; тем – чем; как – так и; когда – тогда же. **б) Соединены два функционально близких, но формально различных элемента:** **не только – но и** (но также, но еще, но притом, но к тому же); **не только – а еще (а также, а кроме того, а притом еще);** не только не – но даже; хотя – но (а, зато, однако, да, только); и так – а тут еще; и без того – а тут еще; мало того что – еще и; не – а; не просто – а; хотя и – но (а, однако, зато); если и – но (однако, зато); хотя – но все-таки (но все же, но тем не менее, но зато); пусть – но (зато); пускай – но (а, зато, однако). в) Соединены два семантически и формально различных элемента: лучше – чем; чем – лучше; едва – как; едва только – как; чуть только – как; лишь только – и; чуть – и уже; чуть только – а уже; не то что – но; не то что – а; не то что – но хотя бы; не то чтобы – но во всяком случае; не то чтобы – но по крайней мере; нельзя сказать чтобы – но; не сказать чтобы – но.

Comment: Источник, в котором упоминается сочетание "не только... а также" вводит логичное ограничение на его употребление: соединение _функционально близких_ элементов. В нашем же примере "поэтическое" и "прозаическое" воспринимаются как две _противопоставляемые_ сущности, из-за чего и возникает вопрос о речевой ошибке, в то время как в случае "... а и" предложение выглядело бы естественным.

Comment: Союз НЕ ТОЛЬКО... НО И находится в этой же группе б). Другое дело,  что  там есть дополнительное деление, поэтому, возможно,  ближе подходит вариант НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО ТАКЖЕ.

Comment: Таким образом, ориентируясь на эту статью, можно подобрать подходящий по смыслу союз. С другой стороны, согласитесь,  один-единственный НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО И,  выбранный по учебным правилам, ОБЕДНЯЕТнашу речь.

Comment: Встречаются ошибки в употреблении союзов и предлогов при однородных членах предложения: В городе построены не только новые школа, больница, а также драмтеатр и библиотека (следовало написать: Не только школа... но и театр).https://helpiks.org/2-14252.html

Comment: Дети пусть используют союз НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО И (это их школьный вариант), но почему нет такого союза в русском литературном языке? В Русской грамматике  (вроде бы академическое издание) указан ряд союзов, никаких стилистических ограничений не приведено, не сказано, что они разговорные или просторечные. А то, что пишут на разных сайтах,  то эту информацию никто не проверяет, почему им следует доверять.

Comment: В каком авторитетном академическом источнике всё это написано, вы можете дать ссылку? И  где можно  увидеть перечень существующих в русском литературном языке союзов. Вы уверены, что в "Русской грамматике" приведены ложные сведения, что ей не стоит доверять. Вы можете это как-то подтвердить?

Comment: Дан список двойных союзов, вероятно, не полный, а в качестве примера. И что с ним делать?  С другой стороны, Корпусная грамматика  - это проект, а не академическое издание. Какой источник авторитетнее? В "Русской грамматике" информация дается более подробно и убедительно, приводится анализ союзов.

Comment: А  откуда такой вывод?  И где говорится о литературных грамматических нормах? (Хотя все эти термины мне не представляются ясными). Где нормируется союз "не только...  но и"? За какую грамматику может поручиться Российская академия наук?

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова где же ваше внимание к источникам? :) РГ–80: «"Русская грамматика" ставит своей целью дать описание современного состояния грамматического строя __русского литературного языка__». Корпусная грамматика — хороший современный проект, там есть интересные статьи, так что в целом ему можно верить (примерно в той же степени, что и РГ–80).

Comment: Всё-всё, я сдаюсь!))) Было очень интересно, большое спасибо, всего доброго!!!

Answer (score 6):

Такого типа  предложения помещают в задание 8  ЕГЭ по русскому языку. Ошибка в построении предложений с однородными членами. Сочинительный союз НЕ ТОЛЬКО..., НО И..., употребляемый при однородных элементах,  нельзя заменять конструкцией НЕ ТОЛЬКО..., *а также.*

Правильно:

***Те из лингвистов, кто занимается исследованием языка художественной литературы, не сомневаются в особой роли глагола не только в поэтическом, но и в прозаическом тексте.***

Comment: А как-то рационально объяснить, почему нельзя заменять, можно? :)

Comment: Нет двойного союза "не только, а также". Есть "не только..., но и", "как..., так и", "не столько..., сколько". Они употреляются с однородными членами.

Comment: Мы говорим: «Не только Васю, а еще Петю, Гришу и Жору». Кажется, двойного союза _не только..., а еще..._ нет, но разве предложение построено неправильно?

Comment: Разве что в разговорном стиле допускается, а в книжных - точно нет.

Comment: А, тогда ведь выходит, что дело в окраске! Но справедливо ли тогда, на ваш взгляд, заставлять детей искать __ошибку__ (!) в этом предложении?

Comment: Да, справедливо. Они должны видеть ошибку. А вот позволять себе ошибаться в устной речи они могут, если позволяет ситуация. Сам Пушкин сказал себе и нам в оправдание: "Как уст румяных без улыбки, Без грамматической ошибки Я русской речи не люблю..."

Comment: Вы меня не поняли: в употреблении разговорных конструкций нет грамматической ошибки. Разговорная лексика — это полноценная часть литературного языка, а упомянутое вами восьмое задание требует обнаружить __грамматические__ ошибки. В чем грамматическая ошибка? Почему нельзя использовать _не только_ рядом с _а также_?

Comment: Неправильно построено предложение с однородными членами. Нарушена структура двойного союза при однородных членах.

Comment: А почему человек __обязан__ употреблять некий двойной союз, если можно выразить мысль другим способом? Разве есть какое-то грамматическое правило?!

Comment: Можно, конечно, выразить мысль другим способом. Но не везде и не всегда. В документах, в текстах научного и публицистического стиля такие ошибки недопустимы. В художественной литературе и в разговорном стиле очень часто встречаются.

Comment: Екатерина, благодарю вас за разъяснения, я оставил голос за. Однако я так и не вижу, где сказано, что неупотребление двойного союза — это грамматическая ошибка в тексте любого стиля. Стилистическая — возможно, но грамматическая — не понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

**Разбор текста:**

Те из лингвистов, кто занимается исследованием языка художественной литературы, не сомневаются в особой роли глагола **не только** в поэтическом, **а также** в прозаическом тексте.

Я думаю, что в данном случае желательно выбрать следующий вариант:

Те из лингвистов, кто занимается исследованием языка художественной литературы, не сомневаются в особой роли глагола **не только** в поэтическом, **но  также** в прозаическом тексте.

**Для решения используем сведения из "Русской грамматики".**

Остановимся на первой группе союзов: **не только – но и (но также, но еще, но притом, но к тому же).**  Эти союзы желательно использовать при обозначении **однородных** (равноправных) отношений, как в нашем случае.

Союз ***не только...а также*** относится ко второй группе: **не только – а еще (а также, а кроме того, а притом еще).** Здесь второй член не соединяется, а присоединяется (**а еще**), поэтому его удобно применять для обозначения присоединительных отношений.

**Примеры:**

Коням предстояло **не только** обрести хозяев, **но также** получить имена, конюшню, право на гражданство в совхозе "Победа". [Виктор Астафьев. Обертон (1995-1996)]

Когда Иван Иваныч приступил к рассказу, и казалось, что его слушали **не один только** Буркин и Алехин, **но также** старые и молодые дамы и военные, спокойно и строго глядевшие из золотых рам. [А. П. Чехов. Крыжовник (1898)]

Это касается **не только** науки, **но также** искусства и политики, в которой также должен быть свой профессионализм. [Дмитрий Лихачев. О русской интеллигенции (1993)]